# Elasticsearch bool query with multiple and/or flows

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to write the below mentioned SQL query using elasticsearch query DSL, but i am not able to get the same result as the SQL query. Can anyone help e with the bool query for the below mentioned case. I am using elasticsearch 2.1.1 version.

```
id.eq(someId)
  .and(
     (anotherId.eq(another).and(node.eq(node)))
     .or
     (domain.in(List))
    )
```

This is what i tried. If this is correct how do i write the same query in Java DSL?

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "id": 1
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "query": {
      "bool": {
         "should": [
            {
               "bool": {
                  "must": [
                     {
                        "term": {
                           "anotherId": "ss"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "term": {
                           "node": "ss"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "bool": {
                  "must": [
                     {
                        "terms": {
                           "domain" : [ "cc", "cc" ]
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the ES query you tried so far? Otherwise, the documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html) provides quite a good explanation on how to transform an SQL query into ES query.

Comment: @Mihali: I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way of doing it in ES 2.1.1

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "id": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "filter": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "anotherId": "ss"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "node": "ss"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  "domain": [
                    "cc",
                    "cc"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It works perfect. can you please review my query below and see if i am going in the right direction? i am not able to cascade the last terms query.                              QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should((QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.termQuery(ANOTHER_ID, "ss"))                       .must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery(NODE, "ss"))).must(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery(DOMAIN,["cc", "cc"]))));

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it, you might be closing the first `bool` query before the first `should`.
If you break your query onto different lines:

```
id.eq(someId)
  .and(
     (anotherId.eq(another).and(node.eq(node)))
     .or
     (domain.in(List))
    )
```

it's a lot easier to see how you can construct the ElasticSearch query:

```
{ 
    "bool" : { 
        "must": [
            { "term": { "id": 15 } },
            { "bool": {
                "should": [
                    { "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            { "term": { "anotherId": "dd" } },
                            { "terms": { "node": [ "ff" ] } }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    { "terms": { "domain": [ "nn", "nn" ] } }
                ]
             }
            }
         ]
     }
}
```

Hopefully the brackets are closing correctly :) Let me know if not and will try to correct them.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Looks like json is invalid with improper braces. And also i am using elasticsearc 2.1.1 version, in which   filtered queries are deprecated (Java API).

Comment: @Val: Can you help me with this?

Comment: I see you've got a correct answer already. There were only a couple of mismatched `{`. This should work as well now.

Comment: This works as well! i wrote the same query using Java API. Please refer below. It may help someone. Let me know if it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Both the query mentioned above marked as answer works fine. In case if someone wants to know how to do nesting of must/should using Java API, please refer this answer. Let me know if it is not working as expected.

```
QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.termQuery(ID1, associationId)).must(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                        .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery(Another_ID, "cc")).must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery(NODE, "cc")))
                        .should(QueryBuilders.termsQuery(DOMAIN, ["cc","cc"])));
```

OR:

```
QueryBuilders.boolQuery().filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery(ID1, associationId)).filter(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                        .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery(Another_ID, "cc")).must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery(NODE, "cc")))
                        .should(QueryBuilders.termsQuery(DOMAIN, ["cc","cc"])));
```